# How do I convert a string into a unique decimal number in python?

Tags: python, string

I need to convert a string, say for instance "Hello world" into a unique decimal number. By unique I mean that the number should be different even if a tiny bit of the string is changed. 
Furthermore, this process must be reversible. This is the process I need:

```
a = "Hello world"

b = someFunction(a)
print(b) --> 4324234

c = inverseOfSomeFunction(b)
print(c) --> "Hello world"
```

I looked through python documentation however I did not find an answer..

Comment: There is no *standard* way of doing this, but you could use the byte values of the character codepoints in a given encoding. Why do you need this?

Comment: Because I'm building a simple encrypting program as a school project

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?  The distinction is important: in Python 2 you're encoding bytes; in Python 3 you'd be encoding Unicode codepoints.

Comment: In Python 3, try: `some_function = lambda s: int.from_bytes(s.encode('utf8') + b'\xff', 'little')` and `inverse_of_some_function = lambda n: n.to_bytes(n.bit_length() // 8, 'little')[:-1].decode('utf8')`

Comment: Python 3, Mark Dickinson, I will try your solution, thanks. Mathias's solution so far is working perfectly

Comment: Mathias's solution looks good to me, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a="Hello WORLD"

def toBigInt(s):
    ret=0
    for i,j in enumerate(s):
        ret+= ord(j)<<(i*8)
    return ret

def fromBigInt(i):
    s=""
    while i>0:
        s+=chr(i&0xff)
        i=i>>8
    return s

i = toBigInt(a)
print i
print fromBigInt(i)
```

This works the following: `ord()` takes the integer representation for one character. Thats between 0 and 255.

The `<<(i*8)` shifts the next letter by 8 bits. Its the same as `*i*265` just more to the point.

The decoding Function always takes the lowest 8 bits (i%0xff) and decodes them. Then it shifts the remaining number 8 bits down.

Comment: Nitpick: how does `toBigInt` distinguish between the empty string and the one-character string `\x00` containing a single null byte?

Comment: @MarkDickinson You are right, all leading and trailing `\x00`s are removed by this implementation. I think you can only circumvent that if you also store the original length and padd with `\x00`s. I was aware of the problem, but didn't care, because for the intended purpose I considered it unimportant.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Correction: The easiest thing to do, pad the string with `\x01` (or whatever) at the beginning and end and strip them on the output.

Comment: Agreed; padding with `\x01` sounds simple and workable.

Comment: thanks to everyone, this post has been really helpful!